# how to add tree knot before label when no children in zkoss

Tags: zk

I am building a dynamic tree in zkoss frame work.in this when no children are there then tree knob(which is used to expand and compress tree by clicking it) is not visible.but my requirement is that even there are no children that knob should be visible.please any one help me to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Add a special object at the first position of your data structure 
and tell your renderer/template to create a non visible for it object.
So, because you have a child you see the knob, but it is not visible so it seems to be empty.